# Hit curb and chunk out of tyre. OK to drive on?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage, fiat

We're on holiday in Mallorca and managed to hit a curb while trying to navigate through a small town.

Rim is scuffed and it cut into the tyre a bit. I will lose excess but insurance will cover. I'm more worried about tyre integrity.

It seems some similar answers on here say not to worry, while others say change it. Any help appreciated.[image][image][image]

Comment: It really isn't worth risking, I'd replace that immediately myself. A few potholes and that could blow out.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can see the metal part of the tire sidewall, which is a dealbreaker as it could lead to a failure of the tire. You need a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You need a new tire. Find out how much the replacement would cost, versus the expense of claiming on your insurance (which will follow you around for years...)

Answer (score 1):

Replace it now or sooner - your safety and others....

Comment: That gash is substantial, and it looks to go all the way to cord.  I agree @Solar Mike.  Too much risk for very little gain.  Finally some insurance works in your favor.  And now looking again I see a split headed into the bead area.  Plain scary.  You won't know for sure until it's off the rim, but by then you're halfway to replacing it...